# Python: how to access objects from a constructor

Tags: python-3.x, constructor, python-import

I have a file `first.py` with the following class

```py
class SampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.standard_tuple = (x1,x2,x3)
```

Now in the file `second.py`, I would like to do the following:

```py
from first import SampleClass
#Other code
imported_tuple = SampleClass.standard_tuple
#Other code
```

However this is not working, "SampleClass has no attribute standard_tuple". I guess I am missing some python basics here:) Anyone with a solution and possibly a clear explanation? Thanks!

I tried to search here and there, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Yes you are missing the basics. You need to first instantiate your class like that : sample = SampleClass(). Then you can access the tuple like that: imported_tuple = sample.standard_tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to Instantiate the class to use the variables in the class.
So your `second.py` file will change to

```
from first import SampleClass
#Other code
sampleClass = SampleClass()
imported_tuple = SampleClass.standard_tuple
#Other code
```

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! I could also just do: `imported_tuple = SampleClass().standard_tuple`